# mysql keeps removing the zero's at start and/or end

Tags: php, mysql

i have a simple form where a user enters a number(product price) and alot of the time it ends with a zero(1.50).
but MYSQL keeps removing the zero's at end making them 1.5 instead of 1.50.

i use the field type double in the table and the php code is a simple form with 1 textbox that passes the number to the DB.

Comment: [Format](http://us.php.net/number_format) that value before displaying it to the user. And don't use floats to represent price, use `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DCoder should post the comment as the answer.
You need to use DECIMAL to represent the price, then you will have trailing zeros.
And you should always format the output.

Comment: thanks for the fast replies guys, it seems i did have the wrong field type, changed it to decimal but it then rounded everything up. but it seems i had the wrong settings should be decimal(4,2) instead of decimal(10,0) that was added by default. all is solved now :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Numeric *values* don't have leading or trailing zeros. `1.5` is the same value as `1.50` is the same value as `1.5000000000`. Numeric types don't save the formatting, they save the *value*. Format the value on output if needed or use a *text* type if you need to save the literal value.

Answer (score 0):

You can store 1.5 in database but you If you want to display it 1.5000000 then it is possible.
You can do this using LPAD like this. Lpad is for adding zeroes on left side and Rpad is for adding zeroes right side.

```
 SELECT LPAD( '1.5', '10', '0' )
 SELECT RPAD( '1.5', '10', '0' )
```

Please give reply if it works.